# Direct traffic to Lambda function with API Gateway in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk, api-design

I am trying to create a REST API to return data to my front-end using a Lambda function all done in CDK.

Basically my api-gateway would route traffic from /uploads to my Lambda function. However, I'm having a bit of difficulty incorporating this.

```
const s3UploaderUrlLambda = new lambda.Function(
  //defined my Lambda function
);


const api = new apigateway.LambdaRestApi(this, 's3uploader', {
    handler: s3UploaderUrlLambda, //I believe this handler means that it will target this
                                  //Lambda for every single route but I only want it for /uploads
    proxy: false
});

const uploads = api.root.addResource('uploads');
uploads.addMethod('GET')
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Define default integration for resource:

```
const uploads = api.root.addResource('uploads', {
  defaultIntegration: new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(
     s3UploaderUrlLambda
  )
});
```

or directly for method:

```
uploads.addMethod(
  'GET',
  new apigateway.LambdaIntegration(
    s3UploaderUrlLambda
  )
);
```